# How to call (using .send()) a smart contract function and send ERC20 token instead of eth?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, erc20

I'm trying to call a smart contract function from web3 using .send() and through send() I want to send an ERC20 token instead of ethers (through value param)

tried this but it doesn't work:

```
await dao.methods.voteForProposal(0).send({
from: accounts[0],
value: contract.methods.transfer("addr", 1).encodeABI(),
});
```

here's the function in smart contract that I'm trying to call:

```
function voteForProposal(int _proposalId) public payable isMember currentlyRaising returns (bool) {
    voteBank[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    voters.push(msg.sender);
    proposalVotes[_proposalId] += msg.value;
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on the Ethereum Stack Exchange: [How to Transfer ERC20 Tokens to a contract on a function call](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110972/how-to-transfer-erc20-tokens-to-a-contract-on-a-function-call)

TL,DR; on receiving the send (or you can even use call) function call, make a transfer of the ERC20 token from within the smart contract function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).